Dynamical system converges to geometric mean
Consider the function $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $F \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 x (y^2 - x^2) \\ 2y(x^2-y^2) \end{bmatrix}$. Consider the corresponding autonomous dynamical system on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by:
$$\begin{align*} \begin{bmatrix} \dot{x}(t) \\ \dot{y}(t) \end{bmatrix} & = F \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \\
x(0) & = a \\ y(0) & = b \\ \end{align*} $$
with $a,b > 0$.
This system has an explicit (albeit very messy) solution, as given by Wolfram Alpha. Looking at the explicit solution, we see that in the limit, we have $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} x(t) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} y(t) = \sqrt{ab}$. I’m really not interested in the explicit solution itself, but I’m interested if there is a way to directly detect that this dynamical system converges to the geometric mean of the initial values.
One partial result in this direction is to recognize this dynamical system as gradient descent with respect to the function $G \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = x^2 - y^2$. For this well-behaved function, Lyapunov theory tells us we will always converge to a zero of $G$, but I don’t see a way to see that we specifically converge to the geometric mean.
I also think this might have something to do with the fact that $G$ is $2$-homogeneous. I’m happy to share my reasoning, but it would take up considerably more space and might be totally irrelevant!

Sure, look at the quantity you are interested in, in this case $\sqrt{xy}$, or, more simply $xy$. Note that the time derivative of $x(t)y(t)$ is zero hence the quantity is constant along a trajectory. Since it converges to a zero of $G$ you get the desired result.
